# White Listing USB's via Udev

Tags: udev

I am planning to whitelist USB Device in such a way that initially everything will be denial ALL followed by whitelisting of certain USB.

I've written these rules in UDEV but it doesn't seem to work. It just denies everything. Here are the rules:

- Deny All:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo 0 > $host/authorized_default; done'"
  ```
- Allow SanDisk Pendrive:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTR{manufacturer}=="SanDisk", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
  ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- The first rule deny the parent node (usb hubs, usb ports,.. to usb devices). Remember sysfs is a Tree.
- You should target the leafs (USB devices).
- Instead multiple rules and trying to manage with `GOTO`, you can use single rule.

Check this one (example of device name in my current machine: `2-1.2:1.0`):

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="[0-9]-[0-9].[0-9]:[0-9].[0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTR{manufacturer}!="SanDisk", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```